# why application proxies examine data in the packet?

Tags: networking, routing

in Packet Filtering as we know : every packet has header and data

and we know thats : Packet filters examine only the header of the packet , because it contains IP source and destination addresses.

my question is why application proxies examine data in the packet?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a proxy.  A proxy makes a separate request to the server the request is intended for.  It has to know *what* is being requested which is in the body of the packet, not the headers.

If you want something that doesn't look inside the packets, use sNAT.  By definition a proxy has to look inside.